# PHP return $this;

Tags: php, this

My question is a simple one.
When returning a var_dump of $this I am getting the object and the properties inside. My question in: Shouldn't it return the methods also?

```
class Test{
    private  $num = 5;
    protected  $dum = 9;

    private function see(){
        return "I see";
    }

    public function returnThis(){
        return var_dump($this);
    }
}

$test = new Test();

$test->returnThis();
```

Result:

```
object(Test)#1 (2) {
    ["num":"Test":private]=>
        int(5)
    ["dum":protected]=>
        int(9)
}
```

Comment: `var_dump()` dumps/outputs the contents of a variable (the values, not the methods) and doesn't return anything. If you want to return `$this`, then you should only have `return $this;`. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to do method chaining? If not, then I don't see the purpose of returning `$this` since you already have the instance in `$test`.

Comment: Are you asking about the *return value* of the method `returnThis()`?  Or are you asking about what's being output to the page by `var_dump()`?  Or something else?  If the latter, in your research about the `var_dump` function where specifically do you see mention of outputting information about an object's methods?  What is the expected result here and why?

Comment: I'm asking about the value of $this.
It clearly shows it's an object and it has 2 properties.
But why doesn't it show the methods too? I'm not trying to accomplish anything. Just wondering why i get infor about the properties but not the methods.

Comment: `var_dump()` is about showing values. If you want to get a representation of a class including methods etc, you can look into the [Reflection API](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php).

Comment: I believe this is what i meant. Showing all information about an object including the methods. And though i knew it can be done using get_class_methods() I believe the Reflection API is what i was actually looking for.
Big thanks to everyone.